# SQLite /Rails datetime query problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm building a Rails application, which is creating orders from a schedule.  The schedule has a time in format hh:mm, and ticks for each day of the week.  A method occasionally checks the schedules, and creates any orders required by the schedule.

Firstly, I build up the time for this week's order in a Ruby DateTime object, then check if it exists, and create if not e.g.:

```
order = Order.where( :delivery_datetime = del_datetime )
unless order.any?
  Order.create( :status => 'Estimated', :delivery_datetime => del_datetime )
end
```

That works as expected on my machine, but when other people picked it up from the repository, it would recreate the orders every time.  I investigated the SQL it was using, and the problem seemed to be it was creating a where clause slightly different to the insert statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE delivery_datetime = '2011-06-30 18:00:00.000000'
INSERT INTO orders (delivery_datetime) VALUES ('2011-06-30 18:00:00.000000000')
```

So the difference is the three extra zeroes in the partial second field.  I understand SQLite doesn't have real date types, so these are different just because the strings are different.  The problem I am having now is that I can't seem to force the format of the inserted string.  E.g. even if I do the following:

```
Order.create( :status => 'Estimated',
               :delivery_datetime => del_datetime.strftime( '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' ) )
```

the insert statement still uses a 'standard' format - but with 6 zeroes on my instance, and 9 on another.

Comment: Seems odd - I've never seen this happen before. Can you show us the code you use to instatiate the del_datetime variable?

Also your Order.where() line can be replaced by Order.find_by_delivery_dateime(del_datetime) followed by "unless order". That will generate a slightly different SQL query - not sure if it will solve your problem though.

Comment: It is instantiated with this horrible bit of code: del_datetime = DateTime.parse( offset_datetime.strftime( "%Y-%m-%d " ) + schedule.delivery_time )  (I'm new to Rails, and I'm sure there is a better option for this bit, but it worked on my machine)

Answer (score 0):

No answers!  Not seen that on Stack Overflow before.  Right now, I have 'fixed' it by declaring the database field as a string, and then using strftime to ensure the date format remains the same.  This works, but doesn't seem ideal.

After reading all the stuff within Sqlite docs about datatypes being a 'misfeature', I'm thinking of dropping it for Postgres or similar.  I want datetimes to be datetimes, and for it not to randomly decide that 18:00:00.000000 and 18:00:00.000000000 are different times...